substrate chain's blocks are getting mined very slow all of a sudden
Earlier the blocks were getting mined with an average of 6 seconds. Now the average time to mine a new block since a day is 9 minutes. All the validator nodes are active.They're running their nodes on contabo. Logs show no errors. I only see the gradual increase in the time taken to mint new blocks

I should check the logs carefully because your network was down and your validators had issues, which caused the target block time to exceed 6 seconds

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
